# Is it possible to Compare two columns in Microsoft SQL server so that the comparison skips punctuation marks and other character like %, ' etc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two columns having data like below.

Column1
AMC Standard, School

Column2
AMC Standard School.

In need to compare these two columns such that comparison is made for the words only and not for any additional, meaning from the above example Column1 and ColumnC are match but due to the Comma ",' and the period sign "." the simple comparison of Column1 and Column2 suggests it as a mismatch.

Comment: Why the MySQL and sqlite tags? (Don't tag products not involved...) Don't store data with those unknown characters. If they are already there, clean up your table data! (And make sure no one can insert those again. (Triggers are great to avoid unwanted input.)

Comment: @jarlh I'd argue that check constraints are better than triggers `;-)`

Comment: @gvee, yes, in most cases check constraints are better. But when it comes to "cleaning" or formatting input data I prefer triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can replace the non comparable characters to empty string (in your case , and .)and then compare them. Something like this.

```
SELECT 1 WHERE REPLACE('AMC Standard, School',',','') = REPLACE('AMC Standard School.','.','')
```

Based on jarlh comments, You should (if possible) update the columns and remove the punctuation marks if they are not using in any comparison and display.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use SQL Servers `SoundEx()` and `Difference()` functions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx respectively)

```
DECLARE @val1 varchar(50) = 'AMC Standard, School'
      , @val2 varchar(50) = 'AMC Standard School.'
;

SELECT @val1
     , @val2
     , SoundEx(@val1)
     , SoundEx(@val2)
     , Difference(SoundEx(@val1), SoundEx(@val2))
;
```

The return value of `Difference()` is between 0 and 4, with a higher number signifying a closer match.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** This type of comparison is not as exacting as a method that cleans up your data beforehand as in those scenarios you can use an exact (`a=a`) comparison, whereas this method looks for *similar* values.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
DECLARE @column1 VARCHAR(100)='AMC Standard, School (Near to ABC Building)'
DECLARE @column2 VARCHAR(100)='AMC Standard, School (Opposite KFC)'

SELECT 'MATCHED' AS COLUMN_COMPARE
WHERE  replace(replace(replace(@column1, ',', ''), '.', ''), substring(@column1, CHARINDEX('(', @column1), CHARINDEX(')', @column1) - 1), '') = replace(replace(replace(@column2, ',', ''), '.', ''), substring(@column2, CHARINDEX('(', @column2), CHARINDEX(')', @column2) - 1), '')
```

Comment: Alright, Thanks for the help buddy.. One more related question if you could answer,, Some columns are having additional values in braces at the end of the statement ,, like "AMC Standard, School (Near to ABC Building)".. or "AMC Standard, School (Opposite KFC)". We would like anything within braces to be skipped? Is this possible somehow?

Comment: I have edited my code. Please make use of this. Please select my answer if my code works for you.